# Gradle maven-publish how to use for multiple projects

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

Might be I am not able to find the appropriate key combination to find out from google for this.

Env: Gradle 2.0

referenced Doc http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html

I have a gradle flat multi level project like

```
root:
  -project1
  -project2
```

using `plugin: 'maven-publish'` I want to install individual project into `maven local repo`.
However when I tried to to execute `publishToMavenLocal` task, its creating `jar` but that jar doesn't have any `class files`.

each individual project has source folder as `src/api/java` and `src/impl/java` I want to install `api` and `imll` separate, if single bundled also its fine.

below are my current `build.gradle` file contents:

```
root:

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "maven"
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

    repositories {
       mavenCentral()
       mavenLocal()
    }

    dependencies {
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.8.2'
    }

    group = 'com.xx.ws.api'
    version = '1.0'
    description = "Common Utils Test."
    targetCompatibility = "1.8"
    sourceCompatibility = "1.8"

    jar {
        manifest.attributes provider: 'test'
    }

    //Gradle Wrapper genrator
    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = '2.0'
    }
}
```

**Project 1:**

```
ext {
    jerseyVersion = "2.10.1"
}

group = "com.xx.ws.api"
version = 1.0

dependencies {
    compile project(':commonutil')
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.5'

    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
    compile (group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers', name: 'jersey-container-servlet', version: jerseyVersion){
        exclude module: 'jersey-client'
        exclude module: 'javax.annotation-api'
        exclude module: 'validation-api'
        exclude module: 'aopalliance-repackaged'
        exclude module: 'javax.inject'
        exclude module: 'hk2-api'
        exclude module: 'hk2-locator'
        exclude module: 'hk2-utils'
        exclude module: 'tiger-types'
        exclude module: 'osgi-resource-locator'
        exclude module: 'jersey-guava'
        exclude module: 'jersey-container-servlet-core'
        exclude module: 'jersey-container-servlet'
        exclude module: 'jersey-common'
        exclude module: 'jersey-server'

    }
//  implCompile (group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.ext', name: 'jersey-spring3', version: jerseyVersion){
//          //excluding a particular transitive dependency:
//          //exclude module: 'cglib' //by artifact name
//          exclude group: 'org.springframework' //by group
//          //exclude group: 'org.unwanted', module: 'iAmBuggy' //by both name and group
//      }

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
}

task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
  classifier "source"
}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            //artifact sourceJar // Publish the output of the sourceJar task
            //artifact source: sourceJar, classifier: 'src', extension: 'zip'
          }
    }
}
```

Please help me with, If I am missing anything or I am completely in wrong path to learn Gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> each individual project has source folder as src/api/java and src/impl/java

By default, Gradle expects your main source folder to be `src/main/java`, if you want to put it in a different place you need to tell gradle where it is [as explained in the user guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#N12116)

Comment: Thanks for the clue, after defining the source folder(like api and impl) its working fine